# Error message running Processing app on Android

Tags: android, processing

I'm trying to run a simple processing app on my Android. The program is below. Nothing complicated - I'm just trying to figure out how to get my processing programs to run on my phone.

```
void setup(){
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  rect(mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100);
}
```

Could somebody please help me figure out why it isn't working. Thanks. This is the error message I get:

[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:396: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this question? I gave as much information as I could. I really would love to know the answer to my question.

Comment: did you choose android mode in Processing?

Comment: try adding size into setup function

Comment: Yes. I chose Android mode. I tried a different very simple sketch with a size and it didn't work. It works if I run it as a JAVA sketch on my computer.

Comment: is this your first try to run something in your phone? did you download the correct API?

Comment: I can run apps on my phone from Eclipse.

Comment: This is the first time I have tried to run from Processing.

Comment: is your computer properly connected to your device? can you verify this from Processing?

Comment: My computer is definitely connected to my device. I don't know how to verify that from Processing.

Comment: One thing I did discover is that when I open SDK manager from processing it is in a different location than when I open SDK manager from Eclipse. I seem to have it installed on my computer in two different locations. So maybe that is causing some sort of problem.

Comment: Maybe. For checking device connectivity from processing, you go to Andorid and then i think there is an option to select device. If you can see your device there and selected, then it's ok

Comment: I decided to uninstall Processing and delete the SDK folder that it was linking to. When I reinstall I will see if I can get it to use the other SDK folder and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, you need to take care of the below:

1)Choose android mode

2)Check device connectivity from Processing

3)Check if you have downloaded the correct API

4)Check SDK path from Processing

5)Check your environment variables

Comment: I deleted Processing and the SDK folder that it was linking to. I reinstalled Processing and linked it to the other SDK folder that my Eclipse was using. And now it works. So there must have been a problem with my SDK. Thanks!